# Android Room Database One-to-One Relation

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to implement a relationship between `Course` and `CourseMeta` with Android Room.

Database design:

[image]

I know that the columns could be all in the course table but I want to add / update courses by time without deleting the meta information. Because of that I thought it could be a solution to extract the meta information in a separate table

```
@Data
@Entitity
public class Course {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String uuid;

    public String name;
 }


@Data
@Entitity
public class Meta {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String courseUuid;

    public boolean isFavorite;
 }

@Data
public class CourseAWithMeta {

    @Embedded
    Course course;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "uuid",
            entityColumn = "courseUuid"

    )
    Meta meta;
 }
```

The problem is, when no meta information for a course exists I want to show default values. Lets say I want to show all courses and mark courses as favorite if the meta information exists. If not, the course should also shown but without marking as favorite.

Is there a way to tell room that the meta table data is not always present and if not it should use default values?

Or should I go another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can add default value by using @ColumnInfo annotation.

`@ColumnInfo(name="isFavorite", defaultValue ="false") public boolean isFavorite`

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()

**Note** : Please check the exact Room library **version** in which defaultValue is available for @ColumnInfo annotation.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, that the meta object is null when no entry exists. I thought there is a way to initialize a new meta object when no reference is found.

Comment: May be default initialisation (Meta meta = new Meta()) with default column values and not assigning value if null work

Comment: Exactly but is there an way to tell room to do so automatically? Like an annotation?